# Standard Regular Expression for Employee ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I need Standard Regular Expression for Employeed ID like

```
EMP015
015EMP
EMP_015
E_015
EMP-015
EMP.VIS
EMP/056
```

Basically it should allow `.` or `_` or `-` or `/` in-between alpha-numeric characters

Conditions:

1. First character should not be `.` or `_` or `-` or `/`
2. Length of Employee ID should be 50 characters.

Comment: What about the last character? Can it be a `.` or a `/` etc. Your example employee ID itself is **51** characters in length.

Comment: Is that maximum 50 characters? Because "EMP015" seems to be less than 50

Comment: @SWeko I assumed the entire string was one employee's ID but yours is a valid question. It's better that the OP clarifies it.

Comment: If you have that many different types of employee ID, why bother validating them at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this for your regex pattern:

```
@"^[A-Z\d]{1}[A-Z\d._/\-]{49}$"
```

Sample code:

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z\d]{1}[A-Z\d._/\-]{49}$");
oRegex.IsMatch("EMP_01512312312312/31-2312.31231231231322222222222"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the regular expressions are not that hard to write if you can explain the format explicitly. I'll make a number of assumptions about the format, correct me if I'm wrong.

1. The format consists of two parts
2. One of the parts is a uppercase alpha string beginning with the letter E, of unknown length
3. The other part is a series of alphanumeric characters.
4. The parts can be in any order
5. The parts can be separated by a single `.`, `_`, `-`,`/`
6. The parts might not be separated at all

Given those, a (quite verbose) regular expression could be:

```
^(E[A-Z]*[._\-/]*[0-9A-Z]+)|([0-9A-Z]+[._\-/]*E[A-Z]*)$
```