# Regular Expression for Employee ID with some restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to build a regular expression which accepts two consecutive special characters like: `/_` or `\\` or `./` or `--` or `\-` or any other combination of special charcters (`./\_-`),in the regular expression mentioned below:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\d]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\d._/\-]{0,49}$
```

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Cool special characters (./_-)

Comment: Please check the edit to make sure that I didn't mess up the meaning of your post.

Comment: You need - so you do that. Now it looks you're asking us to do your job for free.

Comment: So, what exactly _do_ you want to match, and what not? can you give us some examples?

Comment: It seems this is a continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070904/standard-regular-expression-for-employee-id

Comment: do you know that if you **accept** an answer, it makes it worthwhile *for everyone concerned*?

Comment: @zerkms-I have edited my question and i accept my mistake of not framing the question properly.I hope that that this question which is having answer will be useful for other users.I request you to reconsider your vote.

Comment: @stema-I have edited my question and i accept my mistake of not framing the question properly.I hope that that this question which is having answer will be useful for other users.I request you to reconsider your vote.

Comment: @Philip-I have edited my question and i accept my mistake of not framing the question properly.I hope that that this question which is having answer will be useful for other users.I request you to reconsider your vote.

Comment: @Cerbrus-I have edited my question and i accept my mistake of not framing the question properly.I hope that that this question which is having answer will be useful for other users.I request you to reconsider your vote.

Comment: @nhahtdh-I have edited my question and i accept my mistake of not framing the question properly.I hope that that this question which is having answer will be useful for other users.I request you to reconsider your vote.

Comment: @SonerGönül-I have edited my question and i accept my mistake of not framing the question properly.I hope that that this question which is having answer will be useful for other users.I request you to reconsider your vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mlorbetske's regex can be rewritten a bit to remove the use of conditional regex. I also remove the redundant `0-9` from the regex, since it has been covered by `\d`.

```
^[a-zA-Z\d](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|(?<![._/\\\-])[._/\\\-]){0,49}$
```

The portion `(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|(?<![._/\\\-])[._/\\\-])` matches alphanumeric character, OR special character `.`, `_`, `/`, `\`, `-` if the character preceding it is not a special character already. I also make the group non-capturing `(?:pattern)`, since it seems that the regex is used for validation only.

I made use of the zero-width negative look-behind assertion `(?<!pattern)` to assert the character in front is not one of the special characters.

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to match what you're asking for

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\d](?(?<=[\._/\\-])[a-zA-Z0-9\d]|[a-zA-Z0-9\d\._/\\\-]){0,49}$
```

Example

```
Regex.IsMatch("a-12--3", Pattern);    //false
Regex.IsMatch("a-12-3", Pattern);     //true
```

I've used a [conditional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) `(?true|false)` syntax to indicate that if the preceding character (before entering the middle group) is one of the punctuation characters, only non-punctuation characters may follow it, otherwise any of the specified characters are allowed.

The `(?<=expression)` syntax is a [zero-width positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: It is possible to rewrite the regex to not use conditional construct: `([a-zA-Z0-9\d]|(?<![._/\\\-])[._/\\\-]){0,49}`.

Comment: @nhahtdh good call, I'd upvote that ;)

Comment: It doesn't matter anyway, since your current regex works.

Comment: @nhahtdh yours is shorter and more efficient, you should make it an answer

Comment: Thanks nhahtdh and mlorbetske for your answers..